# Most frequent bin in a ggplot2 histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, histogram

I am using `ggplot2` to draw a histogram of a sample of size 1000 taken from a normal distribution. I need to place the letter 'A' on the center of the histogram, and doing that with the function `annotate`.

Since this vector is random, the "center" of the drawing will change a little bit every time I run the code so I need to find a way in which the function knows how to place the 'A' according to that specific sample.For the x axis I took the median of the sample for the Y axis i was thinking of taking the frequency of the most frequent bin and dividing by 2.

Does anybody know if there is a function who gives you the frequency of each bin?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(1000)
qplot(x, geom="histogram")
```

Comment: Please read (1) [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), (2) [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as (3) [how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., provide for example dummy input data, what lines of code you tried etc

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to get the coordinates of the output plot (on a reproducible example):

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- runif(10)
h <- qplot(x, geom="histogram")
ggplot_build(h)$data
```

This will give you all sorts of information on the histogram.

So to get the height of the most frequent class and divide by two, you just need to do

```
height <- max(ggplot_build(h)$data[[1]]$count) / 2
```

---

Using the same kind of information, you can also put the text always right in the middle of the plot:

```
ranges <- ggplot_build(h)$panel$ranges
xtext <- mean(ranges[[1]]$x.range)
ytext <- mean(ranges[[1]]$y.range)
h + annotate("text", xtext, ytext, 
  label="A", size=30, color="blue", alpha=0.5)
```